# Android Keystore Provider - How to store an API key

Tags: android, keystore

In my android app, I receive an API token that I get from an http request

I did some research, and, If it seems the best way to store this key, is with the Android Keystore Provider.

I had a look at the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#UsingAndroidKeyStore

But since i'm new with Android and programing in general, I need some help to put that in place.

I'm not sure in which variable I should save the key :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = cal.getTime();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
Date end = cal.getTime();

KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
kpg.initialize(new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setAlias(alias)
    .setStartDate(now)
    .setEndDate(end)
    .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(1))
    .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=test1"))
    .build());

KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

Then how should i retrieve the key, using (I think) the following code :

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
ks.load(null);
Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The KeyStore is not meant for API keys, it's meant for cryptographic keys (public/private)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that your API token is only valid for a certain period of time. Just store it in a `SharedPreferences` for your application. If it isn't there, or it has expired, just get another one.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. I'll go with SharedPreferences then :)